# CrashData Report and feedback user ios App, use a server

Tags: ios, webserver, hosting

i want integreate in my iOS app, a CrashData Report that send me the log of the crash automatically, and the feedback form to let the user to contact me for request, issue or suggestion, i have found a lot of service online, but the most are payment service, like:

http://www.crittercism.com/

http://www.bugsense.com/

http://www.hockeyapp.net/

or for feedback:

http://www.uservoice.com/

i have also see that there is a opensource for crashdata:

http://quincykit.net/

so maybe the best solution is create my server to host quinckykit, and receive feedback user direct on the server, so my question is, how implement this, what type of server or webhosting i have take?...and what hosting did you advise me, or some tutorial, i never did it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuincyKit contains all you need to receive crash reports and work with them. The hosted solution HockeyApp uses the same open source SDK and provides much more advanced features. If you are not familiar with server hosting php and MySQL, I would recommend to use a hosted solution instead of the open source server component. Also crash symbolication has to be done on your Mac, which HockeyApp e.g. does all automatically for you.

The QuincyKit GitHub repository contains all information you need.

User Feedback is not part of QuincyKit or HockeyApp. I think Crittercism provides some user feedback features independent from crash reporting. I don't know if UserVoice provides anything you can integrate into your iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

You should check Instabug (http://instabug.com) it's very specifically serving feedback reporting with a smooth experience.

It shows a screenshot for the user to draw on other than the text field to enter the feedback in.
It also captures all the device details needed.

You can customize it as you want.

PS. I'm working at Instabug. So let me know if you need any help. It's free btw!